# Simplifying polynomials with non-commutative symbols

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

TLDR: How to have sympy use equalities defined on non-commutative symbols to simplify a polynomial expression?

Detail: I'm looking to simplify a product of multivectors in Clifford algebra. They are defined in terms of basis elements `[e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3]` and have some rules governing them, in particular for `i != j` we have `e_i * e_j = -e_j * e_i` (anticommutativity). I define the symbols and rules of their algebra

```py
import sympy as sp

e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3 = sp.symbols('e_0 e_1 e_2 e_3', commutative=False)

rules = []

# defining the rules of algebra, not essential to understand my question
for i in [e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3]:
    for j in [e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3]:
        if i != j:
            rules.append(sp.Eq(i * j, -j * i))

for e in [e_1, e_2, e_3]:
    rules.append(sp.Eq(e * e, 1))

# e_0 is weird like that
rules.append(sp.Eq(e_0 * e_0, 0))
```

The set of basis vectors has 4 elements but some products cannot be further simplified. I have a reason to believe that `e_large` defined below contains all the terms necessary to express any polynomial of `e_i`.

```py
e = [e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3]
e_large = [
    e_0,
    e_1,
    e_2,
    e_3,

    e_0 * e_1,
    e_0 * e_2,
    e_0 * e_3,

    e_1 * e_2,
    e_1 * e_3,
    e_2 * e_3,

    e_0 * e_1 * e_2,
    e_0 * e_1 * e_3,
    e_0 * e_2 * e_3,

    e_1 * e_2 * e_3,
    e_0 * e_1 * e_2 * e_3,
]
```

Let's define two arbitrary linear combinations of basis elements and their product.

```py
# scalar coefficients for the two terms
a = sp.symbols('a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3')
b = sp.symbols('b_0 b_1 b_2 b_3')

# a nooby way to define a linear combination...
combination_a = sum(a_ * e_ for a_, e_ in zip(a, e))
combination_b = sum(b_ * e_ for b_, e_ in zip(b, e))

product = combination_a * combination_b
# if want to see more interesting terms, we can up the degree of the polynomial
#product = product * product

product.expand()
```

[image]

My question is now how to apply the equations in `rules` to `product` until I arrive only at terms given in `e_large` and then collect the coefficients. I find that calling `product.expand().subs([(e.lhs, e.rhs) for e in rules])` does make reasonable substitutions (below) but the terms are not grouped.
[image]

Calling `.group(e_large)` results in `AttributeError: Can not collect noncommutative symbol`. Furthermore, the `.subs(...)` approach is not bullet proof either: it appears to only perform naive, unidirectional pattern-matching and when I use it on a more complex expression (`product * product`, commented out above) it leaves some terms which could be simplified such as `e_3 e_2 e_3 e_2 -> e_3 (-e_3 e_2) e_2 -> -(e_3 e_3) (e_2 e_2) -> -1 * 1`. My question is how can I best have sympy apply the set of `rules` to simplify `product` and return the coefficients associates with monomials in `e_large`.

PS. I am a sympy noob so do not hesitate to point out if I'm reinventing the wheel somewhere.